# How to auto log on XAML webview using VB

Tags: vb.net, xaml, microsoft-metro

I am making a project for Windows 8 Metro that requires me to log in a local device that has a web interface, for example my router. On the webbrowser control in visual basic I was using `"http://username:password@192.168.1.254/"` to navigate, but in the webview I get a `COMException` error.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it or another way to do this task?